# Determining the Colorspace of a UIImage

Tags: iphone, uiimage, cgcolorspace

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to get the colorspace of an image (i.e. an image loaded into a UIImage)? For example, I have a TIFF image and I'd like to be able to determine if it uses the RGB colorspace or not. Is there an easy way to do this without manipulating pixel data? I know there's some CGColorSpace functions, but none of them seem to do this, just create colorspaces and manipulate them (and much more advanced functions).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to get the color space through CGImage. You can do it with the following line of functions/properties:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) CGImageRef CGImage

CGColorSpaceRef CGImageGetColorSpace (
   CGImageRef image
);
```

So to get the color space of an image, you'd do:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGImageGetColorSpace([myUIImage CGImage]);
```

And of course, make sure to follow the get/create/copy rules for CG objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

To obtain the color space of a UIImage:

```
let colorSpace = myUIImage.cgImage?.colorSpace
```

Example code that checks the color space type:

```
if colorSpace == CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB) && colorSpace != nil {
  print("valid sRGB")
}
```

See [Apple's CGColorSpace Documentation "Accessing System-Defined Color Spaces"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolorspace) for the complete list of color space types.