# How to find if a UIImage is colored or monochrome?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, uiimage, quartz-graphics

Is there a way to find out if a UIImage/(Or the image in any other format) is colored or monochrome? My app intends to read a UIImage(image stored in the Photo app), and then do different set of processing on the image, based on its colorscale (colored image or gray scale).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the color space of the UIImage.  You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4168972/731773).

The mono color spaces are

```
CFStringRef kCGColorSpaceGenericGray
CFStringRef kCGColorSpaceGenericGrayGamma2_2
CFStringRef k​CGColor​Space​Extended​Gray
```

Anything else is color.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (CGColorSpaceGetModel(CGImageGetColorSpace(myUIImage.CGImage)) == kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome) {
    // Image is grayscale
} else {
    // Image allows color
}
```

Note that a "color" image might still only use shades of gray!  A monochrome image can be stored in a color-supporting format.